# VSCode always shows type definition and not the actually implementation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

do any of you face this problem , where vscode always take you to the type definition of a function and not the implementation.

For example,
I right click on the react setState function as below,
[image]

And VS code shows me the typescript file. 
[image]

If its problem a, how do i fix it. 
If not then how do I look at the implementation and not the type definition of a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of VS Code's intellisense. We don't attempt to parse js from inside `node_modules` for IntelliSense, so we have no way of mapping back to the original source code. Instead we rely on `*.d.ts` to provide definitions.

These two issues are tracking possible improvements to this:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6209
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16792

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Matt. Isnt this a very very important feature for 
 a IDE and for the users? why is it not the highest priority for the vscode team? As i see the these above issues date back to 2015 and july 2017.

Comment: Because it's a really difficult problem to solve well and not as useful as it seems at first blush. By using `d.ts` files instead of js files, our IntelliSense is far more efficient and reliable, and we don't have to invest resources to support the crazy dynamic js code that libraries use

Comment: @MattBierner I would argue that the implementation is more important than the types, even if available. You could see how the code is structured and resolving a result. The types just show what the expected input and outputs are (they may not even be correct...). I often see type definitions littered with `any`, making them nearly useless.

Answer (score 1):

In vscode v1.67 there is [update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_typescript-47-support) with new **Go to Source Definition** command

> Jump directly to a JavaScript implementation of a library function
> using the new Go to Source Definition command. You can learn more
> about this feature and share feedback in [TypeScript issue #49003](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49003).

Answer (score -1):

HTML project live preview option on clicking in show in browser the whole project showing that window cannot find web view , type name correctly and then try again

Comment: How does this answer the question?